# Implementing __getitem__ in new-style classes

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this code:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        def method(self, item):
            print self, ": Getting item", item
        self.__getitem__ = types.MethodType(method, self, self.__class__)

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        def method(self, item):
            print self, ": Getting item", item
        self.__getitem__ = types.MethodType(method, self, self.__class__)
```

Then this works fine:

```
a = A()
a[0]
```

But this does not:

```
b = B()
b[0]
```

raising TypeError.

I found that new-style classes look for magic methods in class __dict__ instead of instance __dict__ . Is this right? Why is it so? Do you know about any article explaining the ideas behind? I tried RTFM, but maybe not the right ones or did not catch the thing...

Thank you very much!
Paul

Comment: I'm curious: is there a reason you want per-instance `__getitem__` implementations?  It seems like you are swimming upstream, perhaps there is a better way to achieve your goal?

Comment: I needed to create a class proxy. Basically the `ProxyBase` class takes the target class in its `__init__` and then forwards all method calls to this target (defines `__getattr__`). Then you can make a subclass of `ProxyBase` and (what I expected) e.g. define `__getitem__`. Then the functionality of the proxied object is preserved (well...with some drawbacks...) but with custom behavior of `[]` operator. This works with normal methods, but not with special ones.

Comment: One more comment: Subclassing would be the best, but I need to decorate the existing instance. Not to create a new one of my subclass. I think this is common problem people writing Python like to solve. Basically: How to add some functionality to an existing class. Example: I want to decorate `list` with some methods. I could subclass, but then the "normal" `list` will not have them. I can create instance of my custom class, but then the dict contents would have to be copied. So the idea is to do st. like `ListWrapper([1,2,3])`, which just forwards method calls and reuses the original list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is documented in the Python datamodel documentation: [Special method lookup for new-style classes](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-special-lookup):

> For new-style classes, implicit invocations of special methods are only guaranteed to work correctly if defined on an object’s type, not in the object’s instance dictionary.

and

> The rationale behind this behaviour lies with a number of special methods such as `__hash__()` and `__repr__()` that are implemented by all objects, including type objects. If the implicit lookup of these methods used the conventional lookup process, they would fail when invoked on the type object itself[.]

So, because both `hash(int)` *and* `hash(1)` must work, special methods are looked up on the type instead of on the instance. If `__hash__()` was looked up straight on the object, `hash(int)` would be translated to `int.__hash__()`, and that would fail, because `int.__hash__()` is an unbound method and it expects to be called on an actual *instance* of `int()` (e.g. `1`); so for `hash(int)`, `type.__hash__()` should called instead:

```
>>> hash(1) == int.__hash__(1)
True
>>> hash(int) == type.__hash__(int)
True
>>> int.__hash__()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor '__hash__' of 'int' object needs an argument
```

This is a backwards-incompatible change, so it only applies to new-style objects.

Comment: Thank you for a very good explanation and also for linking to the docs. I skipped this part of the docs a bit because I de facto only need to implement syntactic suggar - the ability to use `inst[index]` instead of `inst.method(index)` and to create the suggar at runtime. I think it is useless to think about `__getitem__` in the same way as e.g. `__hash__`. This is the same as for `list` - You can do `instance_of_list[index]` but you cannot do `list[index]` (which would be nonsense). I hope you see my point of...well...inconsistency.

Comment: @PavelTomasko: No, special casing *all* hooks is *very* consistent. Only special-casing the ones we have a use for now would make for more problems in the future, when uses are found for other hook implementations on the `type` object, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Special methods are only looked up against an object's class if its a new-style class, unlike old-style ones. You're defining the `__getitem__` method on the instance, which has no effect with the new-style class.

Comment: Thank you! I thought this is the point. But was there a reason to make new-style classes to work like this? Where is it said/explained in Python docs?

Answer (score 0):

The default iterators do not use`__getitem__` in new style classes. See http://grokbase.com/t/python/tutor/085k143q1r/new-style-classes-getitem-and-iteration for an example.It seems like the behaviour of `__getitem__` has changed with python 2.2 and the new style of classes