# Overriding __or__ operator on python classes

Tags: python, operator-overloading

As a contrived example, suppose I'm generating a random fruit basket in python. I create the basket:

```
basket = FruitBasket()
```

Now I want to specify specific combinations of fruit that can occur in the basket. Suppose I'm a very picky dude, and the basket either has to be full of apples and pomegranates, oranges and grapefruit, or only bananas.

I was reading up on python operator overloading, and it seems like I could define `__or__` and `__and__` to get the behavior I want. I think I could do something like this:

```
basket.fruits = (Apple() & Pomegranate()) | (Banana()) | (Orange() & Grapefruit())
```

This works just fine making two classes (`Or` and `And`). When `__or__` or `__and__` get called, I just have return a new `Or` or `And` object:

```
def __or__(self, other):
    return Or(self, other)

def __and__(self, other):
    return And(self, other)
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how do I do this without having to instantiate the fruits first? Why can't I use a static `__or__` method on the base `Fruit` class? I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
class Fruit(object):
    @classmethod
    def __or__(self, other):
        return Or(self, other)
```

and assigning the fruit:

```
basket.fruits = (Apple & Pomegranate) | (Orange & Grapefruit) | (Banana)
```

I get an error like this:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'type' and 'type'
```

Any thoughts on how to make this work?

Comment: Why are `Apple`, `Banana` etc. separate subclasses? Could they instead be *instances* of `Fruit`, within the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`__or__` is looked up on the type of the object; for a `Fruit` instance, that'll be `Fruit`; for `Fruit`, that is `type`. You can change the type of `Fruit`, though, by using a metaclass:

```
class FruitMeta(type):

    def __or__(self, other):
        return Or(self, other)


class Fruit(object):
    __metaclass__ = FruitMeta
```

(For Python 3, the syntax is `class Fruit(metaclass=FruitMeta):` instead.)

This then does all that you want. `Apple | Banana` (assuming these two to be subclasses of `Fruit`) will produce `Or(Apple, Banana)`.

Be very careful with this sort of design, though. It's tending into the realm of magic and may easily cause confusion.

(Complete demonstration, in Python 2.7:)

```
>>> class Or(object):
...     def __init__(self, a, b):
...             self.a = a
...             self.b = b
...     def __repr__(self):
...             return 'Or({!r}, {!r})'.format(self.a, self.b)
... 
>>> class FruitMeta(type):
...     def __or__(self, other):
...             return Or(self, other)
... 
>>> class Fruit(object):
...     __metaclass__ = FruitMeta
... 
>>> class Apple(Fruit): pass
... 
>>> class Banana(Fruit): pass
... 
>>> Apple | Banana
Or(<class '__main__.Apple'>, <class '__main__.Banana'>)
```

Comment: just what I was trying to find! Thanks! Works great

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add special (hook) methods as class methods to classes, because they are *always* looked up on the type of the current object; for instances that is on the class, for classes, they are looked up on `type` instead. See [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102407/implementing-getitem-in-new-style-classes/14102566#14102566) for the motivations as to why that is.

That means you need to implement this on the [metaclass](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#__metaclass__) instead; a metaclass acts as the class's type:

```
class FruitMeta(type):
    def __or__(cls, other):
        return Or(cls, other)

    def __and__(cls, other):
        return And(cls, other)
```

then for Python 3:

```
class Fruit(metaclass=FruitMeta):
```

or Python 2:

```
class Fruit(object):
    __metaclass__ = FruitMeta
```