# What is the dunder method for 'or' operator?

Tags: python-3.7

I am looking through the internet and I don't seem to find the right answer. In PyCharm it highlights the dunder methods when you define one. So I tried `__or__` and it highlighted it purple. Then I thought "maybe this is the one", but with a lot of thinking I faced the hard way that `__or__` is for `|`. So how do I override the `or` operator?

Comment: You *cannot* override the `or` (or `and`) operators.  They return without evaluating all the operands (this is called "short-circuiting") as soon as the outcome becomes definite; this is an absolutely critical feature of these operators - and completely impossible to duplicate with a function call.

Comment: aww ok, please make that an answer so I can mark it solved, thnx

Comment: Well, there are workarounds. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15008807/11942268) help?

Comment: um.. well I don't want to use '|' I have it for a different purpose I need to use 'or'