# Is there a way to tell python to stop short-circuit evaluation?

Tags: python, boolean

I want to check if a list contains 1 or 2 or 3

```
    arr = [2,5,7]
    if (1 or 2 or 3) in arr:
      print("true")
    else: 
      print("false")
```

I know this will print false, because of short-circuit evaluation.
However, is there a way I can tell Python to stop this style of evaluation, without laying out each condition?

I've tried any(), all() but they only seem to work for iterables

Comment: @Kache I found a more precise duplicate.

Comment: Voting to reopen. User is not asking about how to "test multiple variables for equality". User is asking a very beginner unfamiliar /w programming idea: whether `or` can be reconfigured to do something different, and the answer is "No, b/c operators tend to do only one thing, otherwise it would be confusing".

Comment: @Kache thank you, that was the answer I was looking for.

Comment: If this question is a duplicate at all, it's more a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62361656/what-is-the-dunder-method-for-or-operator

Comment: I can put it another way: If question context was for a different language where all those operators _could_ be redefined, then the answer to this question would be "Yes it's possible, this X is one way, but maybe try this more idiomatic Y instead...".

Comment: On second thought, that issue can be worked around to some extent. OP: would you accept an answer that uses `|` instead of `or`? Short-circuiting *does* prevent `or` from being used the way you describe, even though it isn't the cause of the actual code's behaviour. I have worked out how to deal with every other issue.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, that would work. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried `any()`, `all()` but they only seem to work for iterables

If you simply want to make these work, please just see [How to test the membership of multiple values in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159313/) as I originally offered.

*What follows is an extremely bad idea, presented purely for educational purposes.*

> I know this will print false, because of short-circuit evaluation. However, is there a way I can tell Python to stop this style of evaluation, without laying out each condition?

There are many things we have to understand before we can write code *laid out similarly to this* to do the job.

1. We **cannot** use `or`, because [it is not redefinable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62361656/what-is-the-dunder-method-for-or-operator). We can use `|`, which is defined using the special method `__or__`. As a bonus, this also has more convenient operator precedence for our purposes.
2. We do have to avoid short-circuit behaviour in order for our code to consider everything that appears on the left-hand side. Fortunately, `|` - doesn't short-circuit - neither do any of the other operators we can implement. (They couldn't possibly, because we implement them *with methods*, and the arguments have to be evaluated before the method can be called.)
3. However, short-circuit behaviour *does not explain* why the original code fails. Operator precedence *also does not explain* why the original code fails. The original code would fail **no matter what** the result of `1 or 2 or 3` was. The only things that can be found `in [2, 5, 7]` are `2`, `5` and `7`, and the evaluation of `1 or 2 or 3` would *not have access to that information*. So even if we came up with some rule that made `1 or 2 or 3` evaluate to (say) `2`, that rule would fail when we change the list to `[3, 5, 7]` - we would have no way to know whether we need the result to be `2` or `3` in order for the code to work.
4. Since `__or__` is a *method*, we need our own class to define it on. That means that *at least one element on the left-hand side needs to be an instance of that class*. Then we can define `__or__` such that it returns another instance.
5. The behaviour of the `in` operator is determined by `__contains__`. However, this can *only* be implemented by the right-hand side - only the container can decide whether it contains something; the element cannot decide that it is in the container. Therefore, we *also need a wrapper class for the right-hand side*. It can, however, be the same class, if we're clever enough.
6. That `__contains__` implementation needs to be aware that it's receiving an instance of the left-hand-side-wrapper class, and implement the necessary logic. (That logic is, realistically, going to use `any`, *which is what we should have just done directly in the first place*. It could also use an explicit `for` loop with `or`, which isn't really any better.)

Putting those pieces together: we will define a class `AnyOf`, which represents a collection of candidates for some operation. We will define `__contains__` in an abusive way: `x` contains `y` (equivalently, `y` is `in x`) if and only if at least one of the candidates represented by `x`, contains at least one of the candidates represented by `y`. We will define `__or__` to make a new `AnyOf` instance, essentially adding the right-hand side to the candidates. This is minimally functional, just for demonstration purposes.

It looks like:

```
class AnyOf:
    def __init__(self, first):
        self._candidates = [first]
    def __or__(self, another):
        result = AnyOf(another)
        result._candidates.extend(self._candidates)
        return result
    def __contains__(self, lhs):
        if not isinstance(lhs, AnyOf): # testing a single item
            lhs = AnyOf(lhs) # wrap it so the main logic can be used
        return any(
            contained in container
            for contained in lhs._candidates
            for container in self._candidates
        )
```

Let's test it:

```
>>> AnyOf(1) | 2 | 3 in AnyOf([2, 5, 7])
True
```

Notice here that I defined things in such a way that the right-hand side wraps a single candidate, which is a list - it does not wrap three separate candidates. (If we want it to work like `AnyOf(1) | 2 | 3 in AnyOf(2) | 5 | 7` instead, then we should not iterate `for container in self._candidates`, because now `self._candidates` is the unique container we care about looking `in`.)

There are other possible enhancements, depending on what relational operators (`==`, `<` etc.) are needed. Similarly, one could define a complementary `AllOf` to represent logical-and logic rather than logical-or. All of these possibilities are left as exercises.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with `set.isdisjoint`. Note that this only works if your elements are hashable (which integers are).

```py
arr = [2, 5, 7]
if not {1, 2, 3}.isdisjoint(arr):
    print("true")
else: 
    print("false")
```

As the other answer has said, you can't easily make `or` do what you want here.

Comment: Please consider providing an answer on the canonical question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159313/ instead (the exact requirements are somewhat vague; it can easily be argued that this "tests the membership of multiple values at once). I don't see any mention of `.isdisjoint` in the answers, and it's worth showing how it's a counterpart to `.issubset`. The current question, however, is specifically about how to make it work with syntax as similar as possible to the non-working version. Otherwise it would just be a duplicate, as far as I can figure out.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That question seems to be primarily concerned with the *all* case, whereas this one seems to want *any*.

Comment: There are answers there covering both, and OP didn't specify. Such is the pain of seeking canonicals on Stack Overflow.