# Assigning __len__() method from another object

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am going to implement some container object.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, L):
        self.L = list(L)
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.L)

class B:
    def __init__(self, L):
        self.L = list(L)
        self.__len__ = self.L.__len__
```

In the first case work both `len()` and `.__len__()`

```
>>> a = A(range(10))
>>> a.__len__()
10
>>> len(a)
10
```

But in the second case I get error with `len()`.

```
>>> b = B(range(10))
>>> b.__len__()
10
>>> len(b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#93>", line 1, in <module>
    len(b)
TypeError: object of type 'B' has no len()
```

1. Why `len()` in second case does not work, whereas `.__len__()` is defined and works correctly?
2. Is it OK in general to assign some methods from one object to another object? Like I did with `self.L.__len__()`.

Comment: What is this, python 2 or 3? Please don't use both tags unless you can tell us that you tried this on both versions.

Comment: Works on 2.6.6 on Linux

Comment: And on 2.7.1 on Windows

Comment: @DJV Because the OP uses old style classes, which don't exist in 3.x any longer.

Comment: Good point, I didn't notice that :)

Comment: I tried it and wrote output on python 3.3. And it works on 2.7 also.

Comment: What platform? Py3.2 on Win fails.

Comment: @heisskopf: `len(B([])` fails on Python 3.3. It fails on 2.7 as well *if you derive `B` from `object`* (new-style class).

Comment: @heisskopf btw you can write `__len__ = lambda x: len(x.L)` in your class definition of `B` to achieve what you want in a short way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this, special hook methods like `__len__` are *always* looked up on the type, not on the instance.

In other words, `len(ob)` calls `type(ob).__len__(ob)`, *not* `ob.__len__()`.

See the [Special method lookup documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup); I explained why this is [in a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102407/implementing-getitem-in-new-style-classes/14102566#14102566).

For methods that are *not* special hooks (starting and ending with double underscores), you are free to assign methods to your instance, there is no *technical* reason preventing you from doing that.

If your goal is to provide a [facade object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) then by all means, copy over methods. I see no obvious downsides to doing that. Calling the method directly on your instance instead of having to route through a wrapper method would perform slightly better (you save a stack push and pop for the wrapper method).

Comment: Now for question 2 ... Is it a good idea?  Personally, in this case, I'd just inherit from `list`, but it's hard to say whether that is the appropriate course of action here or not ...

Comment: In general for non-special methods is it a good idea to assign methods to object from some other object? Like `c.somemethod = c.L.somemethod`

Comment: @heisskopf: As I state: technically it works. If your goal is to provide a facade object, proxying for a wrapped object, I see no reason why that would be a *bad* idea. If you feel it works for your API, I say go for it.

Comment: To my comment above: I am going to call `c.somemethod()` very frequently. Does it have some performance advantage, rather than explicit method definition?

Answer (score 2):

[The fine Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-special-lookup) tells us that

> For new-style classes, implicit invocations of special methods are only guaranteed to work correctly if defined on an object’s type, not in the object’s instance dictionary.